# PHP & Ajax - how to transfer value of textarea to textbox when value is not empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to transfer the value of my textarea to my textbox automatically when the value of the textbox is fetch. how can I do it? here is my code thank you.

```
       <?php

            if(isset($_POST['btnSubcode'])) {
              $lblCode  =  isset($_POST['lblQrTxt']) ? $_POST['lblQrTxt'] : '';

              $code =   $lblCode;
              $code = explode(":",$code); // code = array("QR Code","444444444|123")
              $code = explode("|",$code[1]); // code[1] = "444444444|123"
              $code = trim($code[0]); // 444444444


              $code2 =   $lblCode;
              $code2 = explode(":",$code2); // code = array("QR Code","444444444|123")
              $code2 = explode("|",$code2[1]); // code[1] = "444444444|123"
              $code2 = trim($code2[1]); // 123
            }
            ?>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control-label">code</label>
                <input type="text" id="card-code" value='<?php echo $code ?>' class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control-label">pin</label>
                <input type="text" id="card-pin" value='<?php echo $code2 ?>' class="form-control" maxlength="3">
              </div>
              </form>

///////////////////////////////TEXT AREA///////////////////////
         <textarea class="form-control text-center" id="scanned-QR" name="lblQrTxt"></textarea><br><br>
                               <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="btnSubcode"></input>
```

there is my code, so the value comes in the textarea. so when the value is set i want an automatic transfer on the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by textbox. If you're wanting to copy the value of the textarea to another element (I'll assume with id='textbox'), do this:

```
$('#scanned-QR').change(function() {
    var textToTransfer = $(this).val(); // get text from textarea
    $('#textbox').val(textToTransfer);  // set other element's value
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you are trying to transfer the text area value to all input text boxes. And here is the code will transfer data when click on submit.

```js
$('.btn-primary').click(function(){
  let scannedQR = $('#scanned-QR').val();
  
  if(scannedQR != '') {
    $('input').val(scannedQR);
  } else {
    alert('please scan the QR code and submit');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label">code</label>
    <input type="text" id="card-code" value='sample' class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label">pin</label>
    <input type="text" id="card-pin" value='sample2' class="form-control" maxlength="3">
  </div>
</form>

<br><br>

<textarea class="form-control text-center" id="scanned-QR" name="lblQrTxt"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" name="btnSubcode">Submit</button>
```